# Under what circumstances is regression discontinuity preferred to differences in differences?

Tags: regression, causality, difference-in-difference, regression-discontinuity

I am looking at the adoption of universal health care coverage for children age 6 and under in a country.  The take-up rate was practically 100%.  I want to know the impact of having coverage on doctor visits.  I have data from the year before the policy came into effect and the year after it came into effect.  I can either do differences in differences and see what happened to six year olds and seven years olds in the two years -- or I can  create a panel and do regress discontinuity and see what happens to children on either side of the age divide.  (using a fuzzy approach).  What would you see as the advantages/disadvantages of the two methods?  It's unclear to me.

Comment: Have you checked what, if anything, Mostly Harmless Econometricians recommend?

Comment: I didn't know about this book. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. That's one of the top 5 or so statistics books of the past decade... at least as far as my shelf goes.